# What is wrong with this scheduled task?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have a task that needs to be run at a given time. It needs to send an e-mail before it starts, copy necessary files and invoke an application. 
The batch file code is as follows:

**batchFile.bat**

```
SET userName="someuser"
SET mailer="pre"
cscript //nologo "C:\pre_start_emailer.vbs" %userName% %mailer%
copy "C:\Users\list.xls" "NetworkDrive:\DocumentsList.xls" /Y    
copy "C:\Users\driverScript.vbs" "NetworkDrive\Script\driverMain.svb"   
D:\Programs\myapp.exe
```

In my task scheduler I have enabled, 'Wake the computer to run this task' and also the 'Run whether user is logged on or not' option.
If I have logged into my account, this job runs smoothly, but it **returns a 0x1 result** when I have my PC switched but or if I am logged off.

Any help or suggestions?

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: `copy "C:\Users\list.xls" "NetworkDrive:\DocumentsList.xls" /Y ` - no such thing as `networkdrive:` in windows. Either `C:` or `\\server\share`

Comment: Thanks I figured it out later. I must have probably resolved this :)